# Does the latest Xcode iPhone emulator using iOS 9 allow for genuine iCloud restore?

Tags: macos, iphone, windows, xcode

So I've been trying to find a Windows iOS 9 emulator and failed, but came across Xcode. I have a Windows laptop but I can use either visualbox or VMware to run macOS El Capitan.

I found out that Mac OS has Xcode which is basically an iOS emulator. I need that emulator for one reason only - to be able to use iCloud and restore. From Apple's site I saw a picture of that emulator and saw iCloud option in settings. However, is that emulator capable of something as complex as restoring from an actual active iCloud and copy all my files from my iPhone onto that emulator and show all the files I have on my iPhone on that emulator?

I really don't want to go through all the trouble of running Mac OS on Windows and then Xcode with a potential to mess something up to then realize the emulator cannot restore from iCloud. If any of you guys are aware or would test it and respond, I would be forever grateful. There's a reason I need it done that way so don't bother telling me it's kind of stupid.

Comment: For the people voting to close as off-topic, the question doesn't actually involve software development.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode is not an emulator. Xcode is an integrated development environment (IDE) for macOS and iOS software that happens to include an iOS simulator for the purposes of testing software that is in development.

No, you cannot restore an iCloud backup onto it. It can only be used to run software being developed in Xcode.

Comment: That's a shame, but thank you. Appreciate it.Is there such an emulator that would include an iCloud restore option? Any way to create a separate iPhone IOS system on your PC?

Comment: Apple does not produce such a thing, no. It's extremely unlikely any third-party would, as that would involve decrypting encrypted iCloud backups.

Comment: There's the additional issue that nothing, not even the correct tools on the correct platform, will restore iOS 9 to a device capable of running iOS 10. iOS 9 is simply no longer being signed by Apple & is therefore not an option. iTunes [on Mac or Windows] will allow you to restore the backup, but will at the same time update it to iOS 10.

Comment: If this were possible I would be extremely concerned. This would be an enormous vulnerability, not a feature.